# Why Opera doesnt support cubic-bezier value more or less than "0" and "1"

Tags: css, css-transitions, opera, css-animations

**This will work :**

```
-o-transition: all 600ms cubic-bezier(0.68, 0.2, 0.265, 1);
```

**But not this :**

```
-o-transition: all 600ms cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
```

---

As I tried, If value in `cubic-bezier` less than `1` or more than `1`, It does not work,

*(P0, P1, P2, P3)*

Ex : `cubic-bezier(0, -0.1, 0, 0);` *(P1 less than 1)*

Why ? + What Im missing ?

**Playground :** http://jsfiddle.net/c632m4yu/ (Opera only)

Comment: Are you still testing on Opera 12? Opera removed the need for its prefix in 12.1 according to [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#search=transition) (click on Showing all) and switched to WebKit in version 15 I think

Comment: I tested with all prefix with transition, Still same @FelipeAls

Comment: _`It does not work,`_ in which version of Opera ? 12.17 (Presto)? or 15+ (Blink)?